# What do you call people who control the order at tourists attraction sites

Tags: word-choice, word-request

What do you call the workers who control the public order and environment at tourists attraction sites?

For instance, the job is like the crackdown on fly-tipping or sleeping out in the open or vandalism.

They may work for the city tourism association.

Comment: What word would you use? (in your language(s)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of place they're working. In a museum they're called 'docents'. In a forest or wild area they're called 'rangers'. They might be called 'security guards' in public places. Sometimes the city police or county sheriff do those tasks. There's not one word that covers them all, and two different places of the same type might use different words.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the places I have visited use the term **[tourist police](https://www.tourism-review.com/travel-tourism-magazine-tourist-police-help-the-travelers-and-destinations-category2442)** to describe officers who (to varying degrees) are trained to look after the safety and security of tourists. I am not sure whether their role covers the other items that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of words that could be used, and usually the specific role would indicate the name of the role used.

Some of the words could be:

> Warden - A person responsible for the supervision of a particular place or activity or for enforcing the regulations associated with it.
>   ‘the warden of a nature reserve’
>   ‘an air-raid warden’

https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/warden

> Marshal - An official responsible for supervising sports events, and for controlling crowds in other public events. 
>   ‘ground marshals joined the referee and touch judges in trying to regain order’

https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/marshal

> Groundskeeper - A person who maintains a sports ground, a park, or the grounds of a school or other institution; a groundsman.

https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/groundskeeper

> Steward - An official appointed to supervise arrangements or keep order at a large public event, for example a race, match, or demonstration.

https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/steward

For more ideas you could perhaps look at the names of these jobs when they are advertised by tourist boards or civic authorities.